# Validate Stored Procduer of MySQL based on different condition

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am working on MySQL stored procedure for fetch records from the database.

In stored procedure I have one parameter which is type of shipping company.So I have to add condition in procedure based on parameter ex. If parameter is 'CENTRAL_FULFILMENT' then need to join more tables for filter records but if parameter is 'STANDARD' then need to add some condition inside where clause.

Can anyone please help in in general way how to join table based on if else condition and how to add filter inside where clause based on different parameter.

Thanks.

I am expecting a answer that If I am passing a parameter when calling procedure then based on parameter I need to join different table and need to add different condition inside where clause.
Please show me some example related to this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternatives:

One is to run different SQL queries depending on the conditions.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(IN shippingCompany VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  CASE shippingCompany
  WHEN 'CENTRAL_FULFILMENT' THEN
    SELECT ... FROM table1 JOIN table2 ...;
  WHEN 'STANDARD' THEN
    SELECT ... FROM table1 WHERE ...conditions...;
  ELSE
    ...some other SQL query...
  END CASE;
END
```

The other is to build a string depending on the conditions, then use PREPARE and EXECUTE to run that string as a query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(IN shippingCompany VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = 'SELECT ... FROM table1';

  CASE shippingCompany
  WHEN 'CENTRAL_FULFILMENT' THEN
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' JOIN table2 ...');
  WHEN 'STANDARD' THEN
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' WHERE ...conditions...');
  END CASE;

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```